# Common Lisp: Set scope of symbols in external macro to current package

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to define a utility macro in a package which uses a variable binding 'n in its local scope. I'd like to call this macro from another package without having to prepend the package name to n.

Is this possible?

Here is the code to illustrate the problem:

```
(defpackage #:my-utils
  (:use #:cl)
  (:export #:N-COLLECT))

(in-package :my-utils)

(defmacro n-collect (n form &key (initial-element '()))
  "return a list of n elems prepended to initial-element by
evaluating form n times with the symbol n bound to the iteration
index in the lexical scope of form."
  `(labels
       ((fn (idx seq)
          (if (< idx ,n)
              (cons
               (let ((n idx))
                 (declare (ignorable n))
                 ,form)
               (fn (+ idx 1) seq))
              seq)))
     (fn 0 ,initial-element)))

(n-collect 10 n) ; => (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

(in-package :cl-user)

(my-utils:n-collect 10 my-utils::n) ; => (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

(my-utils:n-collect 10 n) ; -> "The variable N is unbound"
```

BTW: I'm aware that I could export n from :my-utils and (use-package :my-utils) to avoid this, but I'd prefer to keep the symbol n private to the macro.

Comment: So, using `(in-package :cl-user)`, you want `(my-utils:n-collect 10 n)` to return `(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)` and `(my-utils:n-collect 10 my-utils::n)` should end with error?

Comment: Yes, that's what I have in mind. Your question seems to indicate to me you think it's a bad idea. In that case, can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I think you can get pretty close using `intern` - I am not sure whether it's a good idea or not (or if there are any downsides except for package pollution).

Comment: In general, it's better to make the symbol to be bound part of the macro syntax rather than introducing a binding implicitly like this. That's how e.g. DOTIMES and DOLIST works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`macroexpand`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm) to see what is going on:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(macroexpand `(my-utils:n-collect 10 n))

(LABELS ((MY-UTILS::FN (MY-UTILS::IDX MY-UTILS::SEQ)
           (IF (< MY-UTILS::IDX 10)
               (CONS 
                (LET ((MY-UTILS::N MY-UTILS::IDX)) 
                  (DECLARE (IGNORABLE MY-UTILS::N)) 
                  N)
                (MY-UTILS::FN (+ MY-UTILS::IDX 1) MY-UTILS::SEQ))
             MY-UTILS::SEQ)))
  (MY-UTILS::FN 0 NIL))
```

Note that `N` created with `let` belongs to `MY-UTILS` package, so variable `N` (`CL-USER::N`) is unbound.

I think you are looking for [`intern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm)- use `(intern "N")` to create a symbol in the current package.

After you use this macro, symbol `N` stays unbound in your package (`symbolp` T, `boundp` NIL)- if you want to get rid of it, use [`unintern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_uninte.htm).

```
(defpackage #:my-utils
  (:use #:cl)
  (:export #:N-COLLECT))

(in-package :my-utils)

(defmacro n-collect (n form &key (initial-element '()))
  "return a list of n elems prepended to initial-element by
evaluating form n times with the symbol n bound to the iteration
index in the lexical scope of form."
  (let ((n-var (intern "N")))
    `(labels
         ((fn (idx seq)
            (if (< idx ,n)
                (cons
                 (let ((,n-var idx))
                   (declare (ignorable ,n-var))
                   ,form)
                 (fn (+ idx 1) seq))
              seq)))
       (fn 0 ,initial-element))))

(print (n-collect 10 n)) ; => (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

(in-package :cl-user)

(print (my-utils:n-collect 10 n)) ; => (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for! I tried the intern but I did it in the wrong scope.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious approach to something like this is 'don't do that'.  What you're doing is as if, for instance `dotimes` had a syntax like

```
(dotimes (10)
  ... n is always bound to the current index in here, by magic,
  ... whatever the current package is.
  )
```

That would be horrible and nothing would ever do that.  Even `loop` doesn't sink quite so low. (Please do not mention anaphoric macros at this point.  Just ... no.)

Instead, the syntax of `dotimes` lets you *specify* the index variable: `(dotimes (i 10) ...).  So we should do that, instead.  Let's have a syntax like

```
(v-collect (v 10 ...) (+ v v))`
```

for instance.

However `n-collect` also has several other problems:

- it's not hygienic: the name of the local function and its arguments are visible to the form being evaluated;
- it multiply-evaluates the limit argument;
- it will get a stack overflow if the limit is too large.

Finally I am not sure what the initial-element is meant to be: it is in fact the *tail* of the list it builds.  I've assumed that's what you want below.

So to write this thing the first thing, as usual, is to partition it into a macro which expands into a function:

```
(defmacro v-collect ((v n &optional (tail '())) form)
  `(call/collecting (lambda (,v) 
                      (declare (ignorable ,v))
                      ,form)
                    ,n ,tail))
```

This deals with two of the problems:

- hygiene;
- multiple evaluation.

Writing `call/collecting` is then mildly fiddly: you don't want stack overflows and the obvious approach to that is to count *down* not up.  But that will evaluate your form in order from the largest value of the variable down to the smallest which isn't really correct, especially if it has side effects.

A naïve approach is this:

```
(defun call/collecting (f n tail)
  (nconc (loop for i upfrom 0 below n collect (funcall f i)) tail))
```

This solves the stack overflow problem but it traverses the built list again for `nconc`.

This can be made better, of course using the wonders of ancient lisp technology (also known as 'keeping tail pointers'), brought alive today in the form of Tim Bradshaw's [collecting](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#collecting-lists-forwards-and-accumulating-collecting) tools:

```
(defun call/collecting (f n tail)
  (let ((c (make-collector)))
    (dotimes (i n (collector-contents c tail))
      (collect-into c (funcall f i)))))
```

With either of these

```
> (v-collect (n 10) (+ n n))
(0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18)

> (v-collect (n 10 '(a b c)) (+ n n))
(0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 a b c)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, your work and insights are really appreciated!